# React.JS, TypeError: this.state.movies.map is not a function Issue

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, axios

// I am not good at English, so please understand.

When you try to use a map by receiving data from api, you post a message to find a solution because there is a type error.

What's wrong with the code I wrote?

```
.then(data =>
        This.setState({
          movie: data.boxOfficeResult,
          List: data.boxOfficeResult.dailyBoxOfficeList,
          Date: data.boxOfficeResult.ShowRange,
          Type: data.boxOfficeResult.box OfficeType
        })
      );
```

Is this the problem?

I'm practicing how to use api. It's hard.

```
class MoviesCall extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: [],
    list: [],
    Date: "",
    Type: ""
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(endPoint)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          movies: data.boxOfficeResult,
          list: data.boxOfficeResult.dailyBoxOfficeList,
          Date: data.boxOfficeResult.showRange,
          Type: data.boxOfficeResult.boxofficeType
        })
      );
    console.log(this.state.movies);
    console.log(this.state.list);
    console.log(this.state.Date);
    console.log(this.state.Type);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
          <div key={movie.id}></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `data.boxOfficeResult` what type of object is this? It's unlikely to be an array, since on the next lines you're accessing properties like `data.boxOfficeResult.dailyBoxOfficeList`. And if it's not an array, then it has no `.map` function.

Comment: `data.boxOfficeResult.dailyBoxOfficeList `
Deleted but the same error appears.
I can't tell where's wrong.

Comment: @user11904800 can you please do a console log for `this.state.movies` to see whether `movies` is anything array type or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're missing the case when data is not finished loading. By this time in your `render` function should be like this:

```
render() {
  const { movies } = this.state;

  if (!movies || !Array.isArray(movies))
     return null;

  return (
      <div>
        {movies.map(movie => (
          <div key={movie.id}></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From this block I found 3 problem

1) **`This`** should be **`this`**

2) **`movie`** should be **`movies`**

3) **`List`** should be **`list`**

```
.then(data =>
        This.setState({
          movie: data.boxOfficeResult,
          List: data.boxOfficeResult.dailyBoxOfficeList,
          Date: data.boxOfficeResult.ShowRange,
          Type: data.boxOfficeResult.box OfficeType
        })
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the state log the data in the console and see its an array or not . are you using "This" ? it should be "this"

```
.then(data =>
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
          movie: data.boxOfficeResult,
          List: data.boxOfficeResult.dailyBoxOfficeList,
          Date: data.boxOfficeResult.ShowRange,
          Type: data.boxOfficeResult.box OfficeType
        })
      );
```